# How to edit migration details to Office 365

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

I use the Office 365 Business Web interface to migrate IMAP email accounts.
I imported one .csv file with 20 mailboxes. 17 synced and three failed because of a wrong password.

Now I received the correct password for one of the failed accounts.
If possible I would like to edit the password from the one account and delete the two accounts with (until now) unknown password.

**How can I edit the migration details?**

If I import a new migration file it won't allow me to have email addresses which are in previous migration files.

I could delete the existing migration and add a new migration with the new details. But because 17 are synced successfully and will continue to sync with the existing migration I don't want to delete the existing migration.

If I can't edit the file what is the proper way to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Edit  : Edit an existing migration batch. For staged Exchange migrations and IMAP migrations, you can submit a different CSV file. You can also change the migration endpoint used for the migration batch. You can edit only a migration batch that has a status of Created.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/manage-migration-batches

So you could submit a updated csv file.